# R : Know in how many vectors from a list, a value is contained

Tags: r, list, match

I got a list of vectors of words called list_of_sentences.

```
s1=sample(letters,size = 5,replace = FALSE)
s2=sample(letters,size = 7,replace = FALSE)
s3=sample(letters,size = 3,replace = FALSE)
list_of_sentences=list(s1,s2,s3)
```

Suppose, I want to know how many sentences contains the word "a". How would you do that, knowing that I got a list of 50,000 sentences built from 6,000 words. Basically I'm looking for a "vectorized" version of %in% function in order to run something like :

```
vectorized_match_fun("a",list_of_sentences)
TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `%in%` within an apply function.

```
set.seed(13)
s1=sample(letters,size = 5,replace = FALSE)
s2=sample(letters,size = 7,replace = FALSE)
s3=sample(letters,size = 3,replace = FALSE)
list_of_sentences=list(s1,s2,s3)

vapply(list_of_sentences,
       function(x, find) any(find %in% x),
       "a",
       FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
```

Based on your comment on another answer, I will point out that `%in%` accepts vectors on both sides.  The answer I've provided allows you to leverage this, but still only returns a single logical indicating if any match was found.  However, I'm not 100% sure that's what you want, as you haven't provided sample output for how to handle a search for multiple words.

But consider

```
vapply(list_of_sentences,
           function(x, find) any(find %in% x),
           find = c("a", "x"),
           FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
```

Comment: Wow did not know this vapply function. Looks awesome. I'm gonna check it.

Comment: @Benjamin, can you explain me the FUN.VALUE=logical(1)?

Comment: It tells `vapply` to expect a logical vector of length 1 from each iteration of the function.  Telling R what to expect up front allows it to skip some of the memory allocation, providing an increase in speed.  You could drop the `FUN.VALUE` argument and use `sapply` instead and get the same result, but it would take a little more processor time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use lapply:

```
vectorized_match_fun <- function(list_input, matched_word){
    unlist(lapply(list_input,function(x){
        matched_word %in% x
    }))
}

vectorized_match_fun(list_of_sentences,"a")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

vectorized_match_fun(list_of_sentences,"x")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: yeah you right, But I'm afraid this method takes too much time, since I want to compute this kind of operation for 6,000 words. But if this is the unique solution, I will do it ...